# jQuery input .val() or .text()? Both work. .text() safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title mentions, I have a choice to use `.val()` or `.text()` on inputs that I am looping through.

Although `.val('sometext')` is technically right, `.text('sometext')` allows me to loop through span elements too (which are used as prompts if form-filling is invalid.

Is it ok to use `.text()` instead?

Comment: spans aren't inputs, and you shouldn't treat them as such.

Comment: to clarify: I'm seeking to use.text() on inputs.

Comment: technically .text() is basically just a shortcut for `someelement.innerTEXT`. inputs don't have inner text because they're singleton elements.

Comment: Thanks I'll stick with what is safe then.

Comment: `.val` and `.text` have completely different purposes and they are not exchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

[.val()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) works on form elements (or any element with a value attribute?) like `textbox,select,radio buttons,checkbox` etc.

[.text()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) works with `span,div,a etc.` tags

Comment: They are fundamentally different functions also.  Inputs are self closing so `val()` is getting the `value` attribute.  `text` is returning the contents of the tag - between the open and close.  `text` does "work" on `input` tags.  It just gives you nothing because there is nothing between the start/end of the tag because it's self closing.

Comment: @mrrogers you are correct. Exception is `select` tag :)

Comment: true dat... select/option does not have a `value` attr.  good call.

Comment: You can use `val()` on `select` tags to get the actual value of the selected `option` element. In fact that's best practice.

Comment: @Derek you are correct .I have mentioned `select` tag in my answer with `.val()` .

Comment: @mrrogers: Select attributes might not have a `value` *attribute* but they have a value *property*, and that's what `.val` is accessing. The attribute just defines the *initial* value of the element.

Comment: I get that.  That's (basically) what I was trying to say.  `.val()` and `.text()` are fundamentally doing different things.  `.val()` is getting the value of an input field (`input`, `textarea`, `select` etc).  I got it.  Thanks for clarifying.